# manually configure resolv.conf

Tags: networking, centos, dnsmasq, networkmanager

I am trying to setup dnsmasq on my machine, however I am having an issue with setting the order or nameservers correctly.

My interface is assigned DNS servers via NetworkManager and DHCP, and those will, seemingly, take priority no matter what I do; I need to completely ignore the nameserver I am sent via DHCP and use localhost only.

I have tried modifying `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-*`, adding `DNS1=127.0.0.1`, however I am then presented with the fowwloing warning message on restart of NetworkManager

```
dnsmasq[24391]: ignoring nameserver 127.0.0.1 - local interface
```

I have also tried different configurations with

```
/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
dns=dnsmasq # both on and off
```

All with no avail.

I am running CentOS7, and my question is this:

What do I need to configure to ensure that my system always uses 127.0.0.1 as the default, and only nameserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your interface is configured using dhcp, then you should use the dhcp client settings. The setting you probably want to try is supersede domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1 as seen here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136117/ignore-dns-from-dhcp-server-in-ubuntu but I have never tried it in centos, so not really sure which file you need to edit

Comment: woohoo, that was not _exactly_ what I was looking for, but lead me to `prepend`, which adds an additional entry before, instead of overwriting the ones from `dhclient`. Thanks!